# Regular Expressions: Non-Greedy with Stack?

Tags: regex

I have to do a lot regex within LaTeX and HTML files.. and often I find my self in the following situation:

I want something like `\mbox{\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{4}` to be stripped to `\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{4}`. 
In words: "replace every occurrence of \mbox{...} by its content.

So, how do I do that?

The greedy version `\mbox{(.*)}` gets me `\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{4` in $1 and the
non-greedy version `\mbox{(.*?)}` gets me `\sqrt{2` in $1.

Both is not what I want.

What I need is, that the RegEx engine keeps somehow a 
Stack of characters that at the position before and behind `(.*)`, namely `{` and `}`. So, when a new `{` is encountered in `.*`, it should be placed on stack. when a `}` is encountered, the last `{` should be removed from stack. When the stack is empty, `.*` is done.

Similar cases occur with nested HTML Tags.

So, since most regex engines create an FSA for each regex, a stack should be feasible, or do I miss something? Some rare modifier that I'm not aware of? I am wondering, why there is no solution for this.

Of course I could code something for my self with java/python/perl whatsoever.. but I'd like to have it integrated in RegEx :)

Regards, Gilbert

(ps: I omitted to project `+ \sqrt{4}` to keep the example small, `\` should be escaped too)

Comment: This is not possible with standard regexes; an arbitrary depth of nesting cannot be expressed with a regular language.  (Consider the **F** in FSA.)

Comment: hmm, good point. but somehow unsatisfying. I thought this would be a common problem.. which would therefore have some sort of solution.

Comment: Indeed.  The solution is to use a parser that can deal with a wider range of grammars than regex can.

Comment: @Oli Except no modern regex implementation is truly regular. (eg: `(.+)\1` is not a regular)

Comment: We need to know which regex flavor you're using.  Is it one of the flavors associated with languages (Java, .NET, Perl, etc.), or a command-line tool (sed, grep, etc.), or the find/replace widget in an editor (Emacs, vim, EditPad, etc.)?  @Brian has posted a very nice solution, but it only works in .NET.

Comment: As much as I like these regular expressions (and I do), the truth is this task is usually impassible to achieve. I don't know much about LaTeX, but it probably has string literals and comments (which may contain unbalanced braces). It probably also has escaped signs. All of these can get in the way, or make it impossible to *partially* parse the document. If you want it done reliably, you're going to have to use a parser (which I'm sure you can find).

Comment: @Alan Most often I use text editors that support RegEx, frequently TextMate and NetBeans. So far, only the whitespace modifier mattered to me. I would switch to an other editor if necessary, but I use MacOS though. I don't know if the regex engine of .NET is also in Mono.

Comment: I don't use TextMate, but I know its regex support is provided by the [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) library, so I doubt you'll find anything significantly better, regex-wise.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your regex engine but it is possible with the .Net regex engine as follows...

```
\\mbox{(
    (?>
        [^{}]+ 
        |   { (?<number>)
        |   } (?<-number>)
    )*
    (?(number)(?!))
)
}
```

Assuming you are using IgnorePatternWhiteSpace

you can then do `regex.Replace(sourceText,"$1")` to perform the conversion you wished

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP isn't using .NET regexes, but +1 anyway. ;)

Comment: Thanks, at least it looks promising :) Do you know, if MS Editors like VisualStudio or Expression Web support this kind of RegEx? (I'm not sure if they both depend on .NET anyway)

Comment: I don't think so, however you should be able to use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to perform your regex replace

Answer (score 1):

Here's another regex that works in perl http://codepad.org/fcVz9Bky :

```
s/
\\mbox{
  (
    (?:
      [^{}]+     #either match any number of non-braces
      |          #or
      \{[^{}]+}  #braces surrounding non-braces
    )*
  )
}
/$1/x;
```

**Note: It only works for one level of nesting**

Answer (score 1):

Another trick you may be able to use is a recursive regex (which should be supported by PCRE and a few other flavors):

```
\\mbox(\{([^{}]|(?1)+)*+\})
```

Not too much to explain, if you're in the right state of mind.
Here's a similar one, but a little more flexible (for example, easier to add `[]` and `()`, or other balanced constructs):

```
\\mbox\{([^{}]|\{(?1)*\})*\}
```

Comment: I would just like to point to my comment again. That is all. A third option is inline code, but that's usually cheating.